# String Handling in Talend

Tags: string, talend, separator

I have this kind of data,

12345 Lipa AVE, AKA 1234 LIpa AVE, Lipa City, LP, 12345

I want this to transform into this:

[image]

All the data that I'm going to process have 1 comma to separate the address and another case is the 2 comma above.

An example of the 1 comma is below,

12345 Lipa AVE, Lipa City, LP, 12345

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to unify the structure, and then make the mapping. In this case it means first convert the 4 column structure (1 comma case) into 5 columns (2 commas case) where the second field is empty.
The diagram is the following:
`tFileInputFullRow -> tJavaRow -> tExtractDelimitedField -> tMap -> tFileOutputDelimited`

So first read the full row, then detect the case and insert the extra column if necessary. The tJavaRow code is the following:

```
output_row.line = "";
String[] elements = input_row.line.split(",");
if(elements.length == 4)
    elements[0] += ","; 
for(String element:elements)
    output_row.line += element + ",";
```

In tExtractDelimitedField set the separator to comma and finally in the tMap merge the two addresses field into one:

```
row3.address2 != null && !row3.address2.equals("") ? row3.address1 + "," +  row3.address2 : row3.address1
```

The tExtractDelimitedField can be skipped in the tJavaRow by changing the output schema  and then passing the array elements one by one.

Comment: Hello sir, Thank you for the reply. Can you show me an example job for this? I can't quite work it out. Sorry, I'm a bit new on Talend and I'm doing an experiment on how to do this. Thank you! @Ernest

Comment: Try to create a new job and put the components what I have mentioned in the post: `tFileInputFullRow -> tJavaRow -> tExtractDelimitedField -> tMap -> tFileOutputDelimited`
The properties are very intuitive, so I think you will find the right settings very easily. The schemes of the input and output side are a single String column until the tExtractDelimitedField component, where you should change the output schema to 5 columns with string types.